# Restart cucumber tests when background fails

Tags: java, selenium, testing, cucumber, ui-automation

I have a quesiton about cucumber and wondering is it possible to restart my tests if the background steps fail? Basically sometimes my url doesnt load and the tests fail, so its marked as a fail, but i want to be able to restart any tests that fail before the the actual tests start, is this possible?

```
Background:
Given I am on the  application after successful login
And I select create note

#Text Input
@udc @TestRail(536052)
Scenario: Assert Maximum characters are working correctly
When I save user defined component with text "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipisciner" 
Then error text is displayed
```

So id like to restart failing tests before the scenario starts.

Im using selenium and java along with the cucumber

Answer (score 1):

Add a try and catch block into your background step method to make sure if the page is loaded or not. You can wait for an element you are sure it will be shown after the page is loaded, for ex. navigation bar.